# Twenty Ten, dropdown menu appearing with fade effect

Tags: wordpress, fadein, drop-down-menu, twenty-ten-theme

How can I have the Twenty Ten dropdown menu appearing with some fade effect?

If you put your mouse over the "A parent page" it promptly shows a dropdown list with all pages. However, would like to have it showing with some fade effect.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu is implemented using CSS, which cannot produce animated effects. You would have to use some javascript, preferably a library like jQuery, which lets you [apply such effects easily.](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)

You must of course be able to put javascript into your page, which is not possible on pre-configured hosts like wordpress.com.